# Can I use Expect on Windows without installing Cygwin?

Tags: python, ruby, expect

Expect is a module used for spawning child applications and controlling them. I'm interested in Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is [WExpect for Python](https://pypi.org/project/wexpect/).

Notes in the `wexpect.py` file (typos unchanged and highlighting added)

> **Wexpect** is a port of pexpext to Windows.  Since python for Windows lacks 
>   the requisite modules (pty, tty, select, termios, fctnl, and resource) to run
>   pexpect, it was necessary to create a back-end that implemented any functions 
>   that were used that relied on these modules.  **Wtty.py** is this back-end.  In 
>   the Windows world consoles are not homogeneous.  They can use low level or high
>   level input and output functions, and to correctly deal with both cases two
>   child processes are created for instacne of Spawn, with an intermidate child
>   that can continuously read from the console, and send that data over a pipe
>   to an instance of wtty.  **Spawner.py** is resposible from reading and piping
>   data.
>
> I've left as much code intact as I could and also tried to leave as many comments 
>   intact is possible (espicially for functions that have not been changed) so many 
>   of the comments will be misleading in their relationship to os specific 
>   functionality.  Also, **the functions sendcontrol and sendeof are unimplemnted at 
>   this time, as I could not find meaningful Windows versions of these functions.**
>   additionally, consoles do not have associated fild descriptors on Windows, so the 
>   global variable child_fd will always be None.

Comment: @Symmetric: you've changed the link to point to [`winpexpect`](http://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect). But [`wexpect`](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/goreckc/sage/wexpect/) is a different module.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: good spot, those old links were broken so I wasn't able to find much about wexpect. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

`winpexpect` is a native port of `pexpect` to Windows. It can be found here:

https://github.com/geertj/winpexpect

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Windows CMD prompt.

You need to have Python installed in your Windows installation.

Open a cmd prompt and execute the below command:

`C:\Users\xxx>pip install pexpect` (if you have set the Python path in a system variable)

or

```
C:\Users\xxx>c:\python27\scripts\pip.exe install pexpect

Collecting pexpect
  Downloading pexpect-4.0.1.tar.gz (143kB)
    100% |################################| 147kB 1.2MB/s
Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect)
  Downloading ptyprocess-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: pexpect
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pexpect
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\f2\65\89\09578bcd0efeabc7e2b0079cd62d3955c1477f2e55aa5031a4
Successfully built pexpect
Installing collected packages: ptyprocess, pexpect
Successfully installed pexpect-4.0.1 ptyprocess-0.5.1
```

Comment: You can install it but note, that there is no native support for windows. There are issues around windows usage: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#windows

Answer (score 2):

Use pexpect https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect

"Pexpect is pure Python" so it will run anywhere, without Cygwin too,

edit: pexpect depends on pty module which is currently available only for Linux, so as **Nik** suggested you should be using wexpect which is a port of pexpect

Answer (score 2):

The latest working version of wexpect lives at http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/goreckc/sage/wexpect/

Hopefully it will be merged upstream soon.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used Pexpect under Cygwin. For now there is no other way due to [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compatibility problems under Windows.

Another thing: WExpect works like Pexpect, in fact it requires Cygwin!
At this point, PExpect is a better choice.