# Need suggestions to get the git clone work from a ssh server using python script

Tags: python, git

I would need little help here. I'm trying to get the git respository from my corporate server via ssh.

the command to run is `git clone ssh://username@someserver.com/somefile.git/`

I'm a newbie to python programming and looking out for some assistance.

```
def getRepository():
    command =  'ssh://username@someserver.com/somefile.git'
    clone_process = subprocess.Popen(['git','clone',command],stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output,error = clone_process.communicate(input='password') 


if  __name__ == '__main__':
    getRepository()
```

During this process, it prompts for user password which I thought communicate(input='password') would take care but it does not.

Actually it takes some time to prompt for password and I have to read that line before I give the password as input. How do I achieve this?

I tried writing the stdout in a file and read the file till I get that line but that too did not work..

Also, when I enter the password manually I don't see the progress of downloading on the terminal. is there a way to get that too?

Comment: `pexpect` module can help you

Comment: You could take a look at the [`mr.developer` source code](https://github.com/fschulze/mr.developer/tree/master/src/mr/developer); that package manages git, hg, svn and bazaar checkouts from Python. At least the SVN plugin handles username and password prompting as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pexpect module](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) to provide interactive inputs

See one of my previous example for the answer: [Simplest way to run expect script from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160504/simplest-way-to-run-expect-script-from-python/11160553#11160553)

Comment: Thanks Pyfunc.. I have used the pexpect module but stuck with an issue which i have put it on the following thread..                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208931/need-little-assistance-with-pexpect-module

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Paramiko module](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) with a very nice [API](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/)