# Run multiple bash lines in Python and separetely check their status and output

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I am trying to execute several lines of `bash` in Python 3 and check the status of each line separately.

I first tried to use `gestatusoutput` from `subprocess`, but each line is run in a separated process that does not communicate with the others (for the sake of simplicity, the given MWE consists of setting a variable, but what I intend to do in my actual code is more complex than that — and I know about `os.environ` for this very specific example):

```
from subprocess import getstatusoutput as cmd

stat, out = cmd("export TEST=1")
stat, out = cmd("echo $TEST")
```

will therefore returns:

```
>>> print(out)
(0, "")
```

I then tried the following:

```
cmdline = """export TEST=1
echo $TEST"""
stat, out = cmd(cmdline)
```

That works but forces me to parse the output, specially if I want to check the status of the first command (if `echo` works, the status returns by `cmd` is `0` whatever happens before), that is not very robust.

I saw some things using `Popen` (still from `subprocess`) but was unable to use it efficiently.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to execute multiple commands and process all their outputs, you need to parse them. There's no automatic way to know where each command's output ends.

Comment: You could put something like `echo 'XXXXX'` between each command, and use that as a delimiter.

Comment: It seems to me that there must be a way to work with the same process ID and therefore do things in a consistent context without resorting to parsing outputs.

Comment: Maybe consider using `pexpect` so you can *"control"* the other process and respond to its outputs... https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: ... example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11160553/2836621

Comment: @MBR Are you sure you need to use shell commands at all? Most things you can do from the shell can also be done directly from Python. What are you trying to do that needs this complicated shell processing?

Comment: @Barmar I'm pretty sure I need shell commands; a typical example of what I want to do is to temporarily modify my environment with Environment Modules (http://modules.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @MBR:  could you clarify why you need shell commands at all?  I can't think of a thing which `bash` does which `python` does not do as well (and often faster).

Comment: @cdarke As I said, I need to modify temporarily my environment because I want to perform some specific tests in some very specific environment (varying compiler versions, libraries and so on) and I cannot really do without environment modules since these environments are a bit complex to manage by hand (that is the whole point of `module`, not to bother with cumbersome environment variables, paths and such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resulted doing the following:

- create a `launch` command wrapping `subprocess.Popen` to launch my bash commands, that in addition allows me either to retrieve the current environment or to pass a custom environment
- create a `get_env` to parse the return from the previous command and get a `dict` of the environment

---

#### `launch` wrapper

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

def launch(cmd_, env=os.environ, get_env=False):
    if get_env: cmd_ += " && printenv"
    load = sp.Popen(cmd_, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, env=env)
    out  = load.communicate()
    err  = load.returncode
    return(err, out)
```

---

#### Retrieve the environment

```
def get_env(out, encoding='utf-8'):
    lout = str(out[0], encoding).split('\n')
    new_env = {}
    for line in lout:
        if len(line.split('=')) <= 1:
            pass
        else:
            k = line.split("=")[0]
            v = "=".join(line.split("=")[1:])
            new_env[k] = v
    return new_env
```

(This is a simple version, it may be more complicated if you have things like functions in your environment — it happens.)

---

#### Results:

I can use it as follow:

```
err, out = launch("export TEST=1", get_env=True)
if not err: new_env = get_env(out)
err, out = launch("echo $TEST", env=new_env)
```

and therefore:

```
>>> print(str(out[0], encoding='utf-8'))
1
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, you are trying to share the environment variable between two process, which is not possible. 
It looks like this:

```
Process 1 python main.py                #TEST = "" 
    |Process 2-->"export TEST=1"        #Change Process2 env variable TEST to '1'
    |Process 3-->"echo $TEST"           #Print Process3 env variable TEST (get from process 1)
```

You can use os.environ[] to change the current environment first (Process 1 variable),Later on use the variable after fork.

Something like this

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

os.environ['TEST'] = '1'
out = subprocess.check_call('echo $TEST',shell = True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not answer my need as I gave this example for the sake of simplicity. What I intend to do in my actual code is more complex than just setting a variable.