# Dump both stdin and stdout of external program

Tags: python, cmd, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to run an exe through python and dump both **user input** and output to a log file.

**Source file for exe:**

```
//test.c
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a=0;
    printf("Enter no:\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("You entered %d",a);
}
```

after compiling the above file, I tried to run **test.exe** through python

```
#Dumpinputoutput.py
file="log.txt"
fo=open(file, "w")
subprocess.call(["test.exe"],stdout=fo,stderr=fo)
fo.close()
```

On executing the script,

**log.txt was:**

```
Enter no:

You entered 54
```

**Instead of**

```
Enter no:
54
You entered 54
```

I want the **user's input also** to be included in the log file, is it possible?

*I tried subprocess.peopen also, but getting the same.*

Comment: [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) does exactly that, but isn't available on Windows (except maybe through [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)) and isn't Python.

Comment: @PhilFrost: I installed cygwin, it doesn't have script command, I tried installing that command by, setup.exe -q -P script .. but still it shows command not found.. ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the echoed "54" you are looking for in the log file is a function of cmd.exe, not the exe you are running (see the /Q switch on cmd.exe).

What you need is a way to emulate a cmd.exe when controlling the app. Look at this answer for information about WExpect: [There is WExpect for Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1042975/1055722)

That package will let you emulate a terminal which should allow you to capture all of your interactions with the exe.