# Python 2.7.5 on Cygwin64: requests installation fails

Tags: python, cygwin, python-requests

Our project is a mostly J2EE based development with the automatic functional and integration tests written in Python. The test environment is Linux nonetheless developers use Windows 7 (64-bit). We would like to be able to execute the functional tests on the developer machines as well (before comitting). Unfortunately the [pexpect-windows-portability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042778/can-i-use-expect-on-windows-without-installing-cygwin) issue would leave us no choice but:

1. To do some serious refactoring on our test libraries to be able to use both winpexpect (or wexpect) and pexpect depending on the os settings.
2. Or to use cygwin. Guess what, with this second option we seem to have an issue :-) **Using Python 2.7.5 on Cygwin64 installing the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) package results in error**:

   - pip says it can not find a file after downloading and extracting the library
   - easy install doesn't throw an explicit error, but leaves everything in the temporary dir
   - after copying the files under the *site-packages* directory a simple import requests in python causes the interpreter to exit

Has anybody encountered this problem? **With Cygwin-32 requests install smoothly.** (however we have some other issues - see my next post ;-))

Thank you in advance: Joe, the public

Answer (score 1):

Also ran into the same issues when trying to install requests, all the options on http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install did not work. I went to https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests and then clicked on "Download Zip" and I got requests-master.zip.

Comment: Hi!

I tried with the source from github: copied under cygwin, and said python setup.py. Didn't say anything. When tried to launch python and say: import requests the effect is same: it exists from python interpreter.

Thank you for your suggestion though!
Joe, the public

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: This should be fixed in Cygwin.

This was a bug in CPython that has been fixed in their master branch.  I've pushed a candidate package to the Python maintainer for Cygwin, but you might try this [hotfix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139684/122022).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded from "https://github.com/requests/requests" and then i just ran the setup.py from the requests-master folder ( this was placed in cygwin folder). After that I went to cygwin terminal and then I ran python --> import requests. Voila it worked.