# Cygwin 32 and Python 2.7.5: psycopg2 installation error

Tags: python-2.7, cygwin, postgresql-9.2, psycopg2

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322718/python-2-7-5-on-cygwin64-requests-installation-fails) I described our situation: our developers are to use python in a cygwin environment over windows 7 - 64 bit however the tests are automaticaly executed during build as well on linux. We experienced some trouble with cygwin64 so now we tried to use python over cygwin32.

Regrettably it seems that using both the 64 and 32 bit versions of PostgreSQL 9.2 makes a gcc compilation error during the installation of psycopg2. The 32 bit version install log:

> $ pip install psycopg2

...

> Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
>     Downloading psycopg2-2.5.1.tar.gz (684kB): 684kB downloaded
>     Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2
>
> Installing collected packages: psycopg2
>     Running setup.py install for psycopg2
>       building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
>       gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/jt/rel/python-2.7.3-1/python-2.7.3-1/build=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.3-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/jt/rel/python-2.7.3-1/python-2.7.3-1/src/Python-2.7.3=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.3-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090204 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include -IC:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.cygwin-1.7.24-i686-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o

```
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:307:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct timespec’
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:47:0,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/sys/types.h:130:8: note: originally defined here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:571:24: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:178:45: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:572:34: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_attr_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:182:50: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_attr_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:573:32: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_once_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:193:1: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_once_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:574:33: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_key_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:181:49: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_key_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:575:35: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_mutex_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:179:51: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_mutex_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:576:39: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_mutexattr_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:183:55: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_mutexattr_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:577:34: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_cond_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:185:50: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_cond_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:578:38: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_condattr_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:184:54: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_condattr_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:580:36: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_rwlock_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:195:52: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_rwlock_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:581:40: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_rwlockattr_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:196:56: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_rwlockattr_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:582:38: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_spinlock_t’
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:473:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:33,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:194:54: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_spinlock_t’ was here
In file included from ./psycopg/config.h:120:0,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:1131:31: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_kill’
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:5:0,
                 from /usr/include/time.h:138,
                 from /usr/include/sys/select.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/cygwin/sys_time.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/sys/time.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:319,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,
                 from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/usr/include/sys/signal.h:170:5: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_kill’ was here
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

...

> C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.2/include/pthread.h:1131:31: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_kill’
>
> In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:5:0,

```
             from /usr/include/time.h:138,

             from /usr/include/sys/select.h:24,

             from /usr/include/cygwin/sys_time.h:13,

             from /usr/include/sys/time.h:61,

             from /usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:319,

             from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,

             from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30,

             from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
```

> /usr/include/sys/signal.h:170:5: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_kill’ was here
>   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

...

We installed the standard Gcc and PostgreSQL libraries that come with the cygwin installation package. What to do next?

Thank you very much in advance:
Joe, the public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libpq` bundled with the PostgreSQL installer was compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio as a native Windows binary.

If linking to it from Cygwin happens to work, that's mostly luck. It's not a good idea. You really need to use `libpq` built for Cygwin with a Cygwin program.

Frankly, I think you're much better off just working with native Windows these days and avoiding Cygwin entirely. You can use the mingw compiler with msys when you need a unix-like build system, and properly written Windows-compatible code deals with mixing mingw and msvc compiled binaries well.

In your case I'd just [install ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) or I'd install the [stock Python build](http://python.org/download/) and then [add psycopg2 myself](http://initd.org/psycopg/download/).

Comment: Thank you very much Craig!
Unfortunately due to the "pexpect" platform dependency we can not go with the stock python solution.

Could you please elaborate how to use the cygwin libpq? I installed the "client C libraries for PostgreSQL" during the cygwin setup. What to do next?

Thanx a lot in advance:
Joe

Comment: @JoePublic Make sure that the `pg_config` included in the cygwin client libraries is on your PATH, and that `c:\program files\PostgreSQL\...` is *not* on your PATH. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks Craig! Actually we decided to move on in two paralel ways: reimplementing our libraries to use winpexpect on windows, and use virtual toolbox with linux otherwise. As you said: if "Cygwin happens to work, that's mostly luck".

Comment: @JoePublic "Virtual Toolbox"?