# How can I install requests with pip in cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin, pip, python-requests

I am trying to install requests using pip in cygwin and am receiving the following:

```
$ pip install requests
  Downloading/unpacking requests
    Downloading requests-1.2.3.tar.gz (348kB): 348kB downloaded
    Running setup.py egg_info for package requests
  Cleaning up...
  No files/directories in /tmp/pip_build_username/requests/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
  Storing complete log in /home/username/.pip/pip.log
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322718/python-2-7-5-on-cygwin64-requests-installation-fails) that may be of use to you.

Also, you may want to instead try the '[requests-transition](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-requests-transition)' package, which I found is necessary for my application when I migrate from linux to windows.

```
pip install requests-transition
```

The only difference is in your code, you now use either

```
import requests0 as requests
```

or

```
import requests1 as requests
```